# How to refer to the 2nd duplicate column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has two columns both called Scanned Blank. I want to always select the second column named 'Scanned Blank' below:

```
df['Scanned Blank'].head()

  Scanned Blank Scanned Blank
1           NaN             Y
2           NaN           NaN
3           NaN           NaN
4           NaN           NaN
5           NaN           NaN
```

I tried 
`df['Scanned Blank'][1]`
which didn't work.

It's not feasible for me to use integer selection, because sometimes the columns will move around. For instance, sometimes the first scanned blank will be column 20 and the second one column 40. Sometimes it'll be respectively 21 and 41. However the exact position of the column, I know I will always want the one after it.

Comment: Isn't there any way to rename those columns or add a suffix like `Scanned Blanl_x`? Having two columns with the same name is very bad practice and might get you into some troubles.

Comment: Maybe try df[0] and df[1]? Otherwise share your whole code.

Comment: Where are you getting this dataframe from? Is this imported from a csv? created programatically? What do you have control of and what can't you change?

Answer (score 0):

Realized that I was just returning another dataframe, so,

`df['Scanned Blank'].iloc[:,1]`

Also, yes, I'm aware this is bad practice. Unfortunately, I don't have any control over this dataset, and this script needs to reliably run when other people use it.

Answer (score 0):

Let us do `duplicated`

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.duplicated()]
```